# Adding Icons to Show Multiple File Types in Links

Tags: html, css, sass

I implemented on a way to render links on a page like this [link](http://www.flareforhelp.com/2013/04/adding-icons-to-show-file-types/)

This is a page [here](https://www.ers.usda.gov/data-products/food-price-outlook/) that shows the icons displaying with file types. My problem is there are files with the same name, but different file extension. One is a CSV file, the other a excel file. See example below:

Changes in Food Price Indexes, 2015 through 2017 (xls file) 
Changes in Food Price Indexes, 2015 through 2017 (csv file)

I would like to display just one title and have icon links for the file extensions.

Changes in Food Price Indexes, 2015 through 2017 (xls file icon, csv icon)

Here is my CSS

```
span.file a{
display:block;
padding: 1px 0px;
}

span.file a[href*='.pdf'] &[href*='.PDF'] {
background-image: url(/css/images/pdf.gif); 
background-repeat: no-repeat; 
background-position: right center; 
padding-right: 23px;
}
span.file a[href*='.zip'] &[href*='.ZIP'] {
background-image: url(/css/images/zip.gif); 
background-repeat: no-repeat; 
background-position: right center; 
padding-right: 23px;
}     
span.file a[href*='.doc'] &[href*='.DOC'] {
background-image: url(/css/images/word.gif);
background-repeat: no-repeat; 
background-position: right center; 
padding-right: 23px;
}
span.file a[href*='.xls'] &[href*='.XLS'] {
background-image: url(/css/images/xls.gif);
background-repeat: no-repeat; 
background-position: right center; 
padding-right: 23px;
}

span.file a[href*='.csv'] &[href*='.CSV']  {
background-image: url(/css/images/CSV.png);
background-repeat: no-repeat; 
background-position: right center; 
padding-right: 23px;
}
```

Comment: Do you want the icons to be the links for downloading or do you just want multiple icons without adding extra HTML?

Comment: links for downloading preferably.

Comment: On your reference link you have 1 link with a background image offset.  If you can change this to a title (even if it's still a link) and 2 other links, then you can just icons in the form you have on the live link but set the link to display:inline-block; set the overflow:hidden property and set the text-indent to a negative value, e.g. -300px;  Then you can reuse your css classes for setting the background.  Will that get you closer? - Don't forget to set the height and width of the inline-block icon link.

Comment: Shouldn't a "web goddess" already know this stuff? ;-)

Comment: @MyStream I think that should get me closer. I am trying to visualize what you mean. I think I get it..I need more coffee lol

Comment: @RickS LMAO! Too funny!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your URL looks like this:

`<a href="/file.xlsx?v=123">Link Title</a>
<a href="/file.xlsx?v=123" class="xlsx">Download XLS</a>
<a href="/file.csv?v=123" class="csv">Download CSV</a>`

Then you could use CSS like this to generalise the icons:

```
.csv, .xlsx {
    display     : inline-block;
    height      : 16px;
    width       : 16px;
    overflow    : hidden;
    text-indent : -32px;
    position    : relative;
    background  : none scroll no-repeat left top transparent;
}
```

and then customise the background for each:

```
.csv {
    background-image: url(/icons/csv.png);
}
.xlsx {
    background-image: url(/icons/xlsx.png);
}
```